# How to build query strings in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, relational-database

I'm building my php application that relates with a MySQL database. I have some problems doing specific queries since i'm not used doing complex ones. I want to find out how to build query string to do this:
Based on "cad_proc" "sigla" i want to get  "estado" from "juizo" to make sure that i'm  looking for "cad_proc" that have "MG" on it.

```
Table1: cad_proc               
id - sigla  - ...             
01 - MG105  - ...                        
03 - M123   - ...            
Table2: juizo
sigla - estado -...
MG105 - MG
M123  - MG
```

My query so far is:

```
SELECT * FROM cad_processo WHERE sigla like '$UF';
```

Where `$UF` is an input from user.

Comment: What is an example of `$UF`? Putting the input directly in query opens you to SQL injections as well.

Comment: An example of $UF is "MG". I want all the "cad_proc" that their "sigla" have "mg" in "estado"

Comment: The `juizo`'s column, `estado`, has the `mg` in it right? Then the `sigla` in that table should match the `sigla` in `cad_proc`? I'm not seeing why you need `cad_proc`; can't it just be `SELECT sigla from juizo where estado = '$UF'`?

Comment: I need the informations on the "cad_proc" but i only want those who "sigla" equivalent in "juizo" have "mg" in the "estado". The database im using for the application is not designed by me so i have to deal with it the way it is.

Comment: Okay, answer posted which I think should work as you've described.

Comment: If an answer works for you please remember to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is your desired result

```
Select card_proc.*, juizo.estado from card_proc left join juizo on (card_proc.sigla=juizo.sigla) where card_proc.sigla like '%$UF%'
```

Or if you want to do exact match..

```
Select card_proc.*, juizo.estado from card_proc left join juizo on (card_proc.sigla=juizo.sigla) where card_proc.sigla = '$UF'
```

Updated query..

```
 Select card_proc.* from card_proc left join juizo on (card_proc.sigla=juizo.sigla) where juizo.estado = '$UF'
```

Comment: Is there any syntax error or not getting desired result? Please tell me the expected input and output.

Comment: Not desired result. I want the input to be "MG". And output should be all the "cad_proc" elements where their "sigla" equivalent in "juizo" table  have "MG" in "estado"

Comment: Updated query works perfectly! Thanks for the help bro.!

Comment: Glad to know it helped :-)

Answer (score 0):

The right syntax for the function you posted is:

```
"SELECT * FROM cad_processo WHERE sigla = (SELECT sigla FROM juizo WHERE estado like '%".$UF."%')";
```

First off this is not really secure since you are running the risk of an SQL injection this way. To prevent that use bindValue and replace the variable with a keyword. (Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php )

Comment: Thank you for the help, but it stil dont solve my problem since not all "MG" have the same "sigla"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cad_proc.sigla, juizo.estado, FROM cad_proc INNER JOIN juizo WHERE cad_proc.sigla = juizo.sigla AND juizo.sigla = '%".$UF."%';
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesnt seems to work. Not returning any result

Comment: Hi, can you explain your answer a bit? Popped up in the review queue, as code-only answers tend to. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a [`join`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) like this to get the data you want:

```
select cp.sigla from cad_proc as cp
join juizo as j
on j.sigla = cp.sigla
where j.estado = ?
```

Then bind the `$UF`.

It seems like a round-a-bout way of getting the data though. Given the sample data is consistent across the 2 tables I'd just use:

```
SELECT sigla from juizo where estado = ?
```